# Gibt es ein Wort wie "Eltern" für "Tante und Onkel"?

Tags: single-word-request

Gibt es ein Wort, das "Tante und Onkel" zusammenfasst?

So wie "Eltern" oder "Geschwister".

Es würde manche Sätze wesentlich vereinfachen ;)

Comment: Immerhin für Nichten und Neffen gibt es eins: Geschwisterkinder (siehe Literatur aus dem späten 19. Jahrhundert, da wird das oft verwandt).

Comment: Siehe auch http://www.deutsch-als-fremdsprache.de/austausch/forum/read.php?4,55026 oder https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/mama--papa--eltern-oma--opa--grosseltern-was-ist-mit-tante--onkel - Meine Zusammenfassung: Nein, es gibt kein Wort.  Aber _Schweltern_ gefällt mir als neues Wort.

Comment: @knut Ich glaube nicht, dass mir *Schweltern* als Wort für Onkel und Tanten gefallen würde - Ich würde das unbesehen für eine Abkürzung von "Schwiegereltern" halten.

Comment: "Elterngeschwister" würde als neues Wort eindeutig interprätiert werden.

Comment: @Beta meinst du mit Elterngeschwister jene deiner Geschwister die Kinder haben? ;-)

Comment: Bitte um Klarstellung bzw. Anpassung der Frage: Geht es speziell um einen Onkel und eine Tante (ähnlich wie bei "Eltern") oder um eine beliebige Anzahl von Onkeln und Tanten (analog zu "Geschwister")?

Comment: @Beta: Wo ich herkomme hat man auch die Angetrauten der Elterngeschwister Onkel und Tante genannt - ist das nicht im gesamten deutschsprachigen Raum so?

Answer (score 13):

Nein. Es gibt Eltern und Großeltern und Geschwister, aber keinen Sammelbegriff für Onkel und Tanten.

Answer (score 9):

Nein, es gibt im Deutschen kein etabliertes Wort, welches das Paar, das aus einem Onkel und einer Tante besteht, benennt.

Einzelne Leuten mögen dafür vielleicht schon Begriffe erfunden haben, aber vom engsten Freundes- und Verwandtenkreis dieser Worterfinder abgesehen kennt niemand diese Neuschöpfungen. Daher werden sie allgemein nicht verstanden, womit sie unbrauchbar sind.

In Kommentaren wurden bisher genannt:

- **Schweltern**
  Hier würde die Mehrheit der Leser dem Wort nicht ansehen können, was es bedeuten soll. Die meisten werden damit wohl *Schwiegereltern* assoziieren, was aber etwas anderes bedeutet. Außerdem bezeichnet dieses Wort dieses Paar als *Eltern*, also als Personen, die Kinder haben. Das ist aber keine Bedingung um Onkel oder Tante zu sein.
- **Elterngeschwister**
  Dieser Begriff hat eine Bedeutung, die auf der Hand liegt: Es sind die Geschwister der Eltern. Ein Beispiel: Mein Vater hat einen Bruder und eine Schwester, meine Mutter hat einen Bruder und drei Schwestern. Diese sechs Personen sind meine leiblichen Onkel und Tanten. Diese sechs Leute könnte man als meine Elterngeschwister bezeichnen.

  Jeder Einzelne von ihnen ist verheiratet, und diese Ehepartner meiner *Elterngeschwister* sind ebenfalls meine Onkel und Tanten, zwar keine leiblichen, sondern angeheiratete, aber trotzdem meine Onkel und Tanten, jedoch nicht meine Elterngeschwister.

  So wie ich die Frage verstehe, ist aber ein Begriff gesucht, der bedeutet: »Ehepaar, von dem ein Partner eines der *Elterngeschwister* ist«, und dafür eignet sich der Begriff *Elterngeschwister* nicht.

Beachte übrigens, dass *Eltern* ein Paar benennt, während *Geschwister* eine Gruppe von Personen meint, deren Anzahl nicht festgelegt ist. Selbst wenn nur zwei Personen eine Geschwistergruppe bilden, sind diese beiden kein Paar.

Comment: Ich würde "Schweltern" als "Schweineeltern" lesen - spontan will man "Schweine" sagen aber besinnt sich im letzten Moment oder ein wenig zu spät. So wie Bullizei.

Comment: Bitte nicht auf Phantasiebegriffen herumreiten und die Antwort damit unnötig auswalzen. Bringt nichts und verwirrt nur die Leute.

Comment: "das Paar, das aus einem Onkel und einer Tante besteht" - in der Frage ist mE nicht unbedingt nach einem *Paar* gefragt, auch wenn dort "Tante und Onkel" im Singular steht.

Comment: "Beachte übrigens, dass Eltern ein Paar benennt" - auch in diesem Punkt bin ich mir nicht sicher. In unserem sozialen und biologischen Gefüge ist es zwar so, dass "Eltern" ein Paar (und auch nur im Sinn der Anzahl, nicht notwendigerweise der Verbindung) sind, aber ich gehe stark davon aus, dass diese Anzahl kein inhärenter Teil des Begriffs "Eltern" ist.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Erster Satz aus der Frage: *»Gibt es ein Wort, das "Tante und Onkel" zusammenfasst?«* Ich interpretiere das eigentlich recht unzweifelhaft als Frage nach einem Paar.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Zweiter Satz: 'So wie "Eltern" oder "Geschwister".' Ich interpretiere die Nennung von Geschwistern recht unzweifelhaft als Hinweis darauf, dass es eben nicht speziell um Paare geht. (Zumal sich "Eltern" beispielsweise in "Willkommen zum heutigen Elternabend, liebe Eltern!" keineswegs auf zwei Personen bezieht, sondern einfach eine beliebig große und beliebig zusammengesetzte Menge aus *Elternteilen* bezeichnet.) Habe zur Klärung beim OP nachgefragt.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Du bist sehr zuversichtlich. Der OP war das erste und zugleich letzte Mal auf German.stackexchange aktiv als er vor etwas mehr als 2 Jahren diese Frage hier gepostet hat. Außer dieser einen Frage hat er weder eine andere Frage, noch irgend eine Antwort, noch einen Kommentar gepostet. Auch auf anderen Stackexchange-Seiten war er (zumindest mit der hier verwendeten User-ID) niemals aktiv. Sein Profileintrag sagt: »Last seen Aug 25 '17 at 9:37". Daher fürchte ich, dass du sehr lange auf eine Antwort warten müssen wirst.

Comment: In der Frage ist von Ehe keine Rede und es erschließt sich mir nicht, was das Ganze mit Ehe zu tun haben sollte.

Answer (score -3):

Es gibt mehrere mögliche Bedeutungsräume, die *Tante* und *Onkel* bzw. auch *Oheim* und *Muhme* umfassen würden, ohne Anspruch auf Vollständigkeit:

1. Ein Mensch, der mit einem beliebigen oder bestimmten Elternteil verschwistert oder verschwägert ist: ***Elterngeschwister, Elterngeschwager, Vatergeschwister, Vatergeschwager, Muttergeschwister, Muttergeschwager***, auch ***-Geschwieger*** oder ***-Geschwäger*** statt ***-Geschwager***
2. Ein Blutsverwandter beliebigen Geschlechts aus der oder einer beliebigen vorherigen Generation, der nicht in Elternlinie ([Ur-/Erz-/Ober-/Stamm-/Alt-/Ahn-/Groß](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generationsbezeichnungen)-Vater/-Mutter) zur Bezugsperson steht: ***Gevatter***, ggf. mit einem oder mehreren der genannten Präfixe
3. Menschen, die wenigstens eine Nichte oder einen Neffen haben: ***Paten, Gotteltern, Sippeltern, Ammeltern, Aneltern, Nebeneltern, Eltern zweiten Grades*** oder wie 1.
4. Ein Blutsverwandter beliebigen Geschlechts aus der vorherigen Generation (inklusive Vater und Mutter): ***Großelternkinder***, andere Generationen analog, und entsprechend auch *Großelternenkel(kinder)* für die Gesamtheit der Cousins / Vettern, Kusinen / Basen, Geschwister (also Brüder und Schwestern) sowie des Probanden, ggf. auch inklusive der folgenden Generation(en) und bei *Großelternerben* auch inklusive der vorhergehenden

Das sind alles keine geläufigen, regelmäßig verwendete, aber weitgehend selbsterklärende und damit verständliche Bezeichnungen (bzw. Bedeutungen bspw. für *Paten*). Im Allgemeinen würde ich am ehesten noch ***Gevatter*** empfehlen, obwohl das etwas veraltet oder gestelzt klingt.

Comment: Gilt Gevatter für *Onkel und Tanten*, oder sollte man der Vollständigkeit halber noch die Gevatterin erwähnen, die manchmal im Märchen auftaucht?

Comment: Und was davon wäre eine Vereinfachung zu Onkel und Tante?

Comment: kudos für die Erstellung der Liste, aber dies ist m.E. keine Antwort auf die Frage, da alle Begriffe als einzelne gesehen eben nicht Onkel und Tante zusammenfassen, sondern auch hier entweder das eine oder das andere (oder was ganz anderes ^^) meinen

Comment: @Arsak ist Gevatter nicht eigentlich "nur" ein Taufpate? Hätte also mit Onkel und Tante wenig zu tun?

Comment: Ein Gevatter hat nichts mit Blutsverwandtschaft oder angeheirateter Verwandtschaft zu tun - während heute in manchen Gruppen Onkel und Tanten _zusätzlich_ die Rolle des Paten übernehmen, bedingt das eine nicht das andere. Traditionell wurden mit dem Patenverhältnis Beziehungen geknüpft, die eine zusätzlich Absicherung oder sozioökonomische Vorteile für das Patenkind versprachen.

Comment: @mtwde mir ging es nur um die zum Gevatter gehörende weibliche Variante (weil in der Frage nach Onkel **und** Tante gefragt war), nicht um die Art der Beziehung, mit dem Gevattet beschrieben wird.

Comment: @userunknown hat durchaus recht, dass im normalen Gebrauch keine der genannten Bezeichnungen hinreichend Vorteile gegenüber „Tanten und Onkel“ hat.

Comment: @mtwde Die Frage ist ungenau gestellt: vermutlich ist nach 1. ‘Geschwister der Eltern’ gefragt, mglw. auch zusätzlich nach deren Ehepartnern wie Hubert Schölnast in seiner Antwort ausführt, aber da ich mir diesbezüglich nicht sicher war, hatte ich weitere mögliche Antworten aufgezeigt, weil mir das strikte Nein aus der höchstbewerteten Antwort zu einfach und unkonstruktiv war.

Answer (score -3):

Dafür gibt es nur einen wirklichen Begriff, der dieses Beschreibungsproblem für immer löst und alle angeführten Schwierigkeiten berücksichtigt. Eine Neogenese analog des Begriffs der Geschwister. Tante und Onkel zusammen werden beschrieben durch den ultimativen Begriff *trommelwirbel*:
**Getankel**

Comment: Hi user56009, und willkommen auf german.SE! Wir versuchen hier, die deutsche Sprache zu beschreiben, so wie sie tatsächlich verwendet wird. Hast du einen Beleg dafür, dass _Getankel_ verwendet wird? In deiner Antwort klingt es für mich eher so, als hättest du dir das selbst ausgedacht. Wenn du einen Beleg für die tatsächliche Verwendung hast, würde das deine Antwort hier deutlich aufwerten.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach Beleg für die Verwendung ist die Antwort selbst. Mit etwas Humor, der hier Mangelware aber vom Autor durch den Trommelwirbel markiert ist, lässt sich der Wortschöpfung etwas abgewinnen. Das mag daran liegen, dass *Getankel* stark an sein Esperantoäquivalent *geonkloj* erinnert, wo die Vorsilbe *ge-* in Verbindung mit dem Plural *-j* genau die gefragten Verhältnisse ausdrückt. Deshalb von mir ein +1.